# Why me Wifi network is showing disconnected

Tags: networking

I have "HP pavilion 2301ax" in which i am facing wifi problem from 1 month. sometime my wifi works sometime it doesn't. I need to restart my computer to get it working again (sometime it need multiple restart). If it does not work it shows "Wifi network disconnected" (It is not due to my router distance cause router is at the distance of 3 foot). This happens on both Windows and Linux.

here is a screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had The same problem with my HP laptop, In both windows and ubuntu in windows Wifi never worked. I think it's something wrong with your wifi adapter. I switched to LAN. I guess you can too since distance is not a matter.